# Why does ApexPages.StandardController getId return a String?

Tags: apex, platform-bug

I'm writing some new code, and I came across a curious situation. We are using a dynamic piece of code that determines how a record should be handled based on its ID value (e.g. different objects have different fields). The code look briefly like this:

```
public class Mapping {
    public SObjectField name, unitprice, quantity, ...;

    public static Mapping getMapFor(SObjectType entity) {
        // populate a new map based on given values
        if(entity == Opportunity.SObjectType) {
            name = Opportunity.Name;
            unitprice = null;
            ...
        }
        if(entity == OpportunityLineItem.SObjectType) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** The actual code has over a thousand lines of code, caching, etc. Example is illustrative only.

This code works beautifully, since it lets us abstract discrete logic across multiple data types.

As example, we can do:

```
record.put(m.totalprice, (decimal)record.get(m.unitprice) * (decimal)record.get(m.quantity));
```

Instead of writing ten versions of the code that do the exact same function with different records.

Next, there's a component that accepts a standard controller as an attribute. This gives us access to `cancel()`, `save()`, etc that would be available on the actual Visualforce page with very little overhead, and, of course, allows direct access to the record.

Now, here's where the twist comes into play:

```
public class componentController {
    public ApexPages.StandardController controller { get; set; }
    // Other data goes here

    public void init() { // called via action function on component load,
                         // since we can't access controller in constructor
                         // and can't call an action on a component directly.

        // The following line fails to compile
        Mappng m = Mapping.getMapFor(controller.getId().getSObjectType());
    }
}
```

One would wholly expect this code to function verbatim, because `ApexPages.StandardController` `getId` logically returns an Id, right? Right? [Wrong!](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_getId.htm). Instead, it returns a String value.

There's no documentation on why it returns a String, since clearly it will always be an ID value (or will it...?). I have at least two easy workarounds (I'm going to use `controller.getRecord().Id.getSobjectType()`), but I would like to know why the Powers That Be™ decided that they wanted to return a simple String instead of correctly typing the value as an Id.

Is there something I need to know? Are they planning on changing how this function works? Should I not rely on `getId` now or in the future? Could someone fix this so that it works correctly?

Comment: Interesting find; I can only speculate it'd be to make it more generic/versatile in case of bad input, but if it isn't of type id then I'd expect the controller to just throw an uncatchable exception.

Comment: have you tried casting **controller.getId()** as an **id**?

Comment: @amatorVitae That's a workaround. I'm aware I can do that, but that misses the point. That's like String.valueOf(Object) returning an Object instead of String.

Comment: but it is still a solution?  :)   I know **id** s are considered BOTH a string and an id.  When used as an id, SFDC runs a validity check.  That's the only difference between the two

Comment: @amatorVitae Not this time; we need a permanent fix. I'm going to also outline this elsewhere and hope that someone issues a Known Issue for this. A fundamental class shouldn't be broken like this.

Comment: @amatorVitae The problem is that Id inherits from String, which means all Id values are strings, but not all strings are Ids. This subtle semantic could have implications on code where we're expecting an Id, and get a string. Casting is a workaround that suggests that the developer is *accepting a risk that their code may not work in the future*.

Comment: I saw something similar, System.abortJob accepts a string instead of an Id. Maybe there are issue with the Id data type in the underlying java for system methods that make this more complex?

Comment: @ca_peterson You're right. I've *noticed* that, but it didn't register with me at the time. Ever since I've posted about how [`Id.valueOf`](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000929ZIAQ) is broken, it seems they've gone and abandoned the Id data type...

Comment: @sfdcfox why would casting ever break the code?  XXXXX EDIT:  After looking at "Id.valueOf" , I see.  But what could possibly be another work-around?  This is an issue with primitive data types.  Is the only other solution some crazy work-around where you "roll your own" id class??

Comment: @amatorVitae Nothing crazy, no, just a simple cast to an ID (and hope that some future version doesn't break). Fortunately, it seems they fixed Id.valueOf since a year ago, which makes me a little less edgy about it, but I'm still hoping they implement a proper fix. I don't want to have to cast every time I want the record Id.

Comment: The answer (to my mind) is in the documentation: "Returns the ID of the record that is currently in context, based on the value of the id query *string parameter* in the Visualforce page URL."

Comment: off topic: Why are you building a map instead using SObject fieldMap? e.g.: `SObject rec=(SObject)record; rec.put('totalprice', rec.get('unitprice') * rec.get('quantity'));`

Answer (score 3):

It's not uncommon in e.g. MVC frameworks to work like that.

On the Controller, you have some routing information like URL parameters. In the case of SF, we know there's always an Id, so it's safe to add the `getID()` function on the Controller. It simply returns a String; it's a URL parameter, nothing more.

Then, once SF parses the URL information, having fetched the corresponding object data and determined the object's type, it can then create an Object (e.g. Account) that holds object data and also holds information about its type. That type information is then available via the ID of the Object, which is really handy when passing IDs (but not the full Objects) around.

I would argue however that that type information makes only sense as a 'property' of an Object, not so much as a 'property' of a URL parameter. So it might make sense to leave the URL parameter as-is but add type information to the Object nonetheless.

Comment: I'm tempted to believe that, except for one little detail: if you provide an invalid ID for the standard controller, you get an "ID is invalid for SObject type X" error, and your constructor is never called. Contrariwise, you can provide a normal "id" parameter to a Visualforce page without a standard controller, which *should* be a string. I can guarantee with 100% certainty that, today, the ID parameter for the standard controller must always be a ID or null, because Visualforce demands it. However, there's no *contractrual obligation* for it to be an ID, hence my concern.

Comment: Think of it this way: controller.getId() should return the same value as controller.getRecord().Id. However, one returns a string, the other an Id. Instead, we have to think about (Id)controller.getId() or Id.valueOf(controller.getId()), which are both insane, because we *already know it's an ID*. Unless, of course, there is a way to determine that the ID were invalid and thus left to the developer to catch the glitch, *then* it would make perfect sense for it to be a String. Since there isn't, we shouldn't be required to cast from an ID to an ID.

Comment: I agree that being able to construct a controller with an invalid id would be good 'proof' of my assumptions, and I agree that that proof is not there. Salesforce is indeed being smart: it knows that a controller without valid id does not make sense, so it doesn't allow constructing one when the id is invalid. Moreover, SF already names the function getid() (instead of geturlparam1()). Yet, the only reason I can think of why it returns a string is that it treats it like a URL param. As for the constructor *not* being able to handle a String, that's weird. Let's hope an SF employee knows why :)